# mySQL get number of visitors in store in X minute increments

Tags: mysql, time, distribution

I have a database that picks up a user's MAC address whenever they walk by a node. The node is situated such that they must pass it upon entering, and exiting a venue. I would like to know how many visitors are in the venue at any given time (continuous would be great, but discrete X minutes chunks is also fine).

With the following query I get the below results:

```
SELECT MACAddress, MIN(fg_HubDataTable.timeOfRec) as entryTime, MAX(fg_HubDataTable.timeOfRec) as exitTime
FROM fg_HubDataTable
WHERE fg_HubDataTable.venueID = 2 AND eventDate = '2013-02-22'
GROUP BY fg_HubDataTable.MACAddress, fg_HubDataTable.eventDate
HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(fg_HubDataTable.timeOfRec), MAX(fg_HubDataTable.timeOfRec)) > 120
```

The order of the data is: MAC Address, Entry Time, Exit Time

```
001CB3BAXXXX    2013-02-22 22:05:05 2013-02-23 00:34:09
001F1FA8XXXX    2013-02-23 01:17:06 2013-02-23 02:49:12
002608A8XXXX    2013-02-22 18:09:05 2013-02-22 19:12:05
0026BB9DXXXX    2013-02-22 23:13:03 2013-02-23 01:30:04
0026FF6DXXXX    2013-02-22 23:32:06 2013-02-23 01:26:03
```

Answer (score 0):

For a time `X`, a visitor `V` is in the park for that time if their most recent entrance `En` that has a `time < X` is later than their most recent exit `Ex` that has a `time < X` OR no exit has a `time < X`.

e.g. if a visitor entered at t = 2, exited at t = 3, entered at t = 4 and exited at t = 5, they are in the park at t = 2.5 (since they have not exited yet), not in the park at t = 3.5 (since their most recent exit < 3.5 is later than their most recent entrance), in the park at t = 4.5 (since their most recent entrance < 4.5 is later than their most recent exit) and so on.

Using this information, you can construct a query that for a given timestamp counts all the visitors that would be in the park during that timestamp, and spit out that as a number, and run the query over a certain set of timestamps (such as minutely or hourly).